# How should this be implemented? Delegation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, delegates, delegation

I have many views that I want to communicate with one other view. We'll call that one other view "main view". What I want to do is have the "many other views" be able to send a method to "main view" that adds a subview. Would I create a delegate method? If so, would I create the delegate in the "main view" and then have to set it in the "many other views". I am just wrapping my mind around how delegates work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term 'delegate' is usually used only when an object is sufficiently general and will be reused in many situations with many possible different delegates. For example, a table view, a very generic object, has a delegate that customizes its behavior, but a custom view of your own making that is used for your own purposes might not.

It sounds like you have a very simply many-to-one relationship between your "other" views and your "main" view. You can probably simply make a property on your "other" views (e.g. `mainView`), or make some other method which allows your "other" views easy access to the "main" view pointer, and send your message to it.

Comment: So, I would be better off creating a class method (not an instance method) in "main view" that shows my view? Then, create a pointer to "main view" in each of the "many views" and then send "main view" class the created method from the "many views"? If this is the case, I cannot call [self.view addsubview:whateverSubviewController.view] in a class method.

Comment: Or, should I set the target of the button that invokes the action to the "main view" view controller and create an instance method in the "main view" that shows the subview?